# Significado do warning: Possible overdraw

Tags: android, warnings

Tenho uma aplicação no qual está mostrando o *warning*:

> Possible overdraw: Root element paints background 
>   @color/md_elegance_green with a theme that also paints a  background (inferred theme is
>   @android:style/Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen)

A imagem ilustra o momento do acontecimento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz algumas pequisas porém não consegui compreender muito bem.
O que significa *overdraw*? Como eu devo fazer o tratamento para que não aparece mais esse *warning*?

Comment: No tema do manifest,xml aponta para um tema enquanto a cor do layout diz outra. Apenas um aviso que pode haver um overdraw - sobreescrever uma cor que já foi aplicada. Retire a linha "android:background="@color..." que o warning não mais aparecerá.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo mas eu realmente quero que neste layout tenha um background diferente do tema principal. Qual sua sugestão quanto a isso?

Comment: Defina essa cor no tema.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida mas quero que a cor do fundo deste layout seja diferente do tema. Entende?!

Comment: @seamusd Então você deveria definir um tema diferente para esse layout. Temas podem ter outros temas como pai, herdando todas as características dele. Aí você sobrepõe o fundo. Veja a resposta do Hugo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994454/possible-overdraw-root-element-paints-background

Answer (score 1):

declara seu tema no arquivo: **res/values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="MeuTema" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:background">@color/md_elegance_green</item>
</style>
```

E utiliza esse tema no Manifest.xml

```
android:theme="@style/MeuTema"
```

***// EDIT***

parent="android:Theme" você coloca um tema superior. No seu caso acredito que seria Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen